# Passar ID PHP para Janela Modal Jquery

Tags: php, id

Preciso finalizar um projeto urgente e há algo que preciso fazer e não tenho a minima ideia de como se faz.
Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro de alunos, onde vou pesquisar por nome, cpf ou horário de aula.

Em todos os métodos de pesquisa serão pesquisas não exatas, quer dizer que vai me trazer mais de um resultado do banco de dados. Quero que, ao clicar no nome de quem apareceu, abra uma janela modal Jquery com os dados completos dessa pessoa para que seja editado ou adicionado mais um ou outro. Vou aplicar isso em outras partes do sistema e preciso disso urgente para poder continuar.

Separei e gravei um video apresentando o problema e apresentando um pouco o sistema, segue link no youtube:
https://youtu.be/iWwHJI8Kl0k

Segue meu PHP Inteiro:

```
    <!-- Modal Avisos -->    
        <div id="boxes">
            <div id="dialog" class="window">
              <div class="title-modals"> <div class="img_warm"> </div> <h3> Aviso </h3></div>
              <div class="cont-modal">
                <?php 
                    if($acao == "search_name") {
                      if(empty($_POST['nome'])) {
                        echo"<h3> Campo Nome Vazio, favor preencha para poder pesquisar!!! </h3>";
                      } else{
                        if($check_name != 1) {
                          echo"<h3> Nome não encontrado, favor verifique e tente novamente! </h3>";
                        }
                      }
                    };
                    if($acao == "search_cpf") {
                      if(empty($_POST['cpf'])) {
                        echo"<h3> Campo CPF Vazio, favor preencha para poder pesquisar!!! </h3>";
                      } else{
                        if($check_cpf != 1) {
                          echo"<h3> CPF não encontrado, favor verifique e tente novamente </h3>";
                        }
                      }
                    };
                    if($acao == "search_time") {
                      if(empty($_POST['select_time'])) {
                        echo"<h3> Campo Horario de Estudo Vazio, favor preencha para poder pesquisar!!! </h3>";
                      } else{
                        if($check_time != 1){
                          echo"<h3> Horario não encontrado no banco de dados, favor entrar em contato com o Administrador do Sistema! </h3>";
                        }
                      }
                    }
                ?>
              </div> <!-- final .cont-modal -->

              <a title="Fechar janela de confirmação" class="close">Entendi</a><br />
            </div>
            <!-- Máscara para cobrir a tela -->
            <div id="mask"></div>
        </div> <!-- final #boxes01 --> 

        <div id="boxes02">
            <div id="dialog02" data-id="<?php $id = $_GET['ID']; ?>" class="window02">
              <?php 
              $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE Dia_Horario LIKE '%".$searched_time."%' " );

              $check_time = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($check_time >= 1){
                   while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $radio = $ln['ID'];
                    $id = $ln['ID'];
                    $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                    $hora_estudo = $ln['Dia_Horario'];
                }
                }
              ?>
              <form>
                <lable for="txt-nome"> Nome:</lable><input type="txt" id="txt-nome" name="nome" class="txt" value="<?php echo $full_name; ?>" />
              </form>
              <a title="Fechar janela de confirmação" class="close02">X</a><br />
            </div>
            <!-- Máscara para cobrir a tela -->
            <div id="mask02"></div>
        </div> <!-- final #boxes01 --> 


        <div class="result-table">

          <div class="menu-top">
              <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">
                <div  style="background-color:#06F;" class="bt-top">
                   Alunos 
                </div> <!-- .bt-table -->
              </a>

              <a href="http://www.dpaulatreinamentos.com/system/teste01/views/pages/colaboradores.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <div  class="bt-top">
                   Colabores 
                </div> <!-- .bt-table -->
              </a>
          </div> <!-- .menu-table -->

          <div id="form">
            <form id="form_nome" class="forms" method="post" action="?acao=search_name">
              <label for="txt-nome"><h3> Nome   </h3></label> <input type="text" name="nome" class="txt-medium txt" id="txt-nome" /> 
                <div class="tooltip">
                  <input type="submit" value="" class="sb-search-small bradius"/>
                  <span class="tooltiptext">
                    Pesquisar Por Nome
                  </span>
                </div> <!-- final .tooltip -->
            </form>
            <form id="form_cpf" class="forms" method="post" action="?acao=search_cpf">
              <label for="txt-cpf"><h3> CPF:    </h3></label> <input type="text" onkeypress="mascara(this, '###.###.###-##')"  name="cpf" maxlength="14" class="txt-small txt" id="txt-cpf" /> 
                <div class="tooltip">
                  <span class="tooltiptext">
                    Pesquisar Por CPF
                  </span>
                    <input type="submit" value="" class="sb-search-small bradius"/>         
                </div> <!-- final .tooltip -->

              <div class="tooltip">
                <a href=""> <div class="bt-more-small"> </div> </a>
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                  Cadastrar Aluno
                </span>
              </div> <!-- final .tooltip -->



            </form>
            <form id="form_search_class" class="forms" method="post" action="?acao=search_time">
              <lable for="select_time"> <h3> Dia e Horário: </h3>  </lable> <select id="select_time" class="bradius txt-time" name="select_time">
                  <option value="valor1"><?php 
                      $select_time_database = "SELECT * FROM horarios_aulas";
                      $check_time = mysql_query($select_time_database) or die (mysql_error());
                                 while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($check_time)) {
                                  $selected_time = $ln['Horario'];
                                   echo"<option value='$selected_time'> $selected_time </option>";
                                 }
                        ?>
                  </option> 
                </select>
              <div class="tooltip">
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                  Pesquisar Por horarios
                </span>
                <input type="submit" value="" class="sb-search-small bradius"/>
              </div> <!-- final .tooltip -->

              <div class="tooltip">
                <a href=""> <div class="bt-more-small"> </div> </a>
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                    Cadastrar novo horário de aula
                </span>
              </div> <!-- final .tooltip -->

            </form> 

         </div> <!-- final #forms -->

            <table class="com_table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">  </th>
                  <th scope="col"> ID </th>
                  <th scope="col">Nome </th>
                  <th scope="col">Hora e Dia Estudo</th>
                  <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                  <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>


                <?php //seleciona toda a tabela

                    if($startaction == 3){
                      if($acao == "search_cpf") {
                        if(empty($_POST['cpf'])) {
                          echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';
                        } else {
                        //pegar cpf via post
                        $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
                        $cpf = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $cpf);

                       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE CPF LIKE '%".$cpf."%' " );

                        $check_cpf = mysql_num_rows($result);
                          if($check_cpf >= 1){

                             while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                              $id = $ln['ID'];
                              $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                              $cargo = $ln['Cargo'];
                    ?>

                        <tr>
                          <a href=""><td> <?php echo $id; ?></td>  </a>
                          <td> <a name="modal01" href="#dialog01" onclick="$('#modal-container').load('<?php echo $id; ?>', function(){$('#dialog01').modal('show');})" > <?php echo $full_name; ?> </a> </td> 
                          <td> <?php echo $cargo; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php
                      } } else {
                        echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';
                      }
                      }
                    }
                    }   

                    if($startaction == 4){
                      if($acao == "search_name") {
                        if(empty($_POST['nome'])) {
                          echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';
                        } else {
                        //pegar nome via post
                        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE Nome_completo LIKE '%".$nome."%' " );

                        $check_name = mysql_num_rows($result);
                          if($check_name >= 1){

                             while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                              $id = $ln['ID'];
                              $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                              $hora_estudo = $ln['Dia_Horario'];

                  ?>


                       <tr>
                        <a href=""><td> <?php echo $id; ?></td></a>
                         <a href="#TD"> <td> <a data-id="" href='#dialog01' name="modal01" id="<?php  echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $full_name; ?> </a> </td> </a>
                         <td> <?php echo $hora_estudo; ?></td>
                      </tr>




                    <?php

                      } } else {
                        echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';

                      }
                      }
                    }

                    }

                    ?>

                <?php
                if($startaction == 5){
                      if($acao == "search_time") {
                        if(empty($_POST['select_time'])) {
                          echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';
                        } else {
                        //pegar nome via post
                        $searched_time = $_POST['select_time'];
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE Dia_Horario LIKE '%".$searched_time."%' " );

                        $check_time = mysql_num_rows($result);
                          if($check_time >= 1){
                             while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                              $radio = $ln['ID'];
                              $id = $ln['ID'];
                              $full_name = $ln['Nome_completo'];
                              $hora_estudo = $ln['Dia_Horario'];

                  ?>

                    <div class="scroll-y">

                       <tr>
                        <td> <a data-toggle="modal02" data-target="#dialog02" href="#<?php echo $radio; ?>"> Clicar Aqui</a></td>
                        <a href=""><td> <?php echo $id; ?></td></a>
                         <a href="#TD"> <td> <a data-toggle="modal02" data-target="#dialog02"href='#dialog02' name="modal02" id="<?php  echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $full_name; ?> </a> </td> </a>
                         <td> <?php echo $hora_estudo; ?></td>
                      </tr>

                    </div>


                    <?php

                      } } else {
                        echo'<script type="text/javascript">abre_modal( \'#dialog\' );</script>';

                      }
                      }
                    }

                    }

                    ?>


                </table>
          </tbody>
      </div> <!-- final .result-table -->

        </div> <!-- final .container -->     
  </body>
</html>
<?php
```

Comment: Um jeito de se fazer é com JavaScript e AJAX. Quando o cara clicar no botão de editar, o Javascript pega o ID e faz uma requisição AJAX em um arquivo PHP, esse arquivo PHP faz o select no banco, trazendo os dados do registro que você precisa. Depois disso, você preenche os dados do modal com Javascript.

Comment: Não é de editar, os dados já vao aparecer no proprio modal já com os campos liberados para edição, depois eu só faço um update no banco ai já é mais facil, eu gravei um video e postei no youtube para poder ajudar a compreender meu problema.

Comment: Então... quando clicar no nome do usuário, faz um AJAX que pegue os dados daquele registro e popula a modal com Javascript.

Comment: Esse é o problema, eu não sei fazer isso em javascript, só sei fazer em PHP

Comment: Estude sobre AJAX, então. O que não falta é conteúdo por ai de AJAX com PHP e jQuery.

Comment: Deve ter algum jeito de fazer isso com Jquery e PHP, Jquery no modal e php no Back-end

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Comment: O jeito que eu falei é exatamente assim. PHP no back-end e jQuery no modal.

Answer (score 0):

- Resultados da busca `PHP`:
  `...
  echo ("<a href='#' classe='nomecompleto' title='".$full_name"'>".$full_name."</a>");
  ...`
  Guarde os dados no lado do cliente deste jeito, assim não precisa fazer uma segunda consulta quando quiser editar.
- jQuery + LocalStorage 
  Ao clicar no nome do estudante, o mesmo é copiado para a localStorage
  Código`jquery`:
  `$('document').ready(function (){
  $('.nomecompleto').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('nome', $(this). attr ('title'));
  });
  });`
  Agora o nome do estudante foi guardado no localStorage
- No modal ou qualquer outro lugar 
  Supondo que `#editarnome` é o `id` do `input` para edição do nome, carrega automaticamente o nome do estudante guardado na localStorage
  `$('#editarnome').val() = localStorage.getItem('nome');`

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Não funcionou,continua mostrando o ultimo registro

Comment: Você tem skype? vamos marcar para conversar assim você pode me ajudar melhor

Comment: Skype: agneliox . Infelizmente só poderá ser amanhã

Comment: Tudo bem, sem problemas, já te enviei a solicitação

Comment: Podemos marcar um dia e horario para conversar Agnélio?

Comment: Mostra o último registo apenas porque você fez um loop é só usou o resultado no final do loop. Deixa elaborar melhor...

Answer (score 0):

Penso que deves fazer o seguinte exibir todos os resultados

```
   <?php 
              $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE Dia_Horario LIKE '%".$searched_time."%' " );
$check_time = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<ul>";  // adicionado
if($check_time >= 1){
                   while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                   echo "<li>".$ln['Nome_completo']."</li>";   //adicionado   
                }
                }
echo "</ul>"; // adicionado
              ?>
```